# Print map in LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet

I am new in LeafletJS. I am trying to print map in LeafletJS. My code for print is like this:

```js
     printProvider = L.print.provider({
      capabilities: printConfig,
      method: 'GET',
      dpi: 254,
      autoLoad: true,
      // outputFormat: 'pdf',
      customParams: {
          mapTitle: 'Print Test',
          comment: 'Testing Leaflet printing'
      }
  });
  // Create a print control with the configured provider and add to the map
  printControl = L.control.print({
      provider: printProvider
  });
  map.addControl(printControl);
```

But when I click the print button error comes like this

```
Proxy Error.
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /mapfish-print/pdf/print.pdf.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Print-Any-Part-Of-Your-Page-Print.html) to print a map.

The code is as simple as

```
$('#map').print();
```

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWraBJ).

Answer (score 2):

Have you added this line to your html ?

```
<script src="http://apps2.geosmart.co.nz/mapfish-print/pdf/info.json?var=printConfig"></script>
```

Plus I think you have to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed to add some host to the list of allowed hosts in config.yaml in your mapfish print server.

If you want to allow all hosts you can add:

```
- !ipMatch
  host:0.0.0.0
  mask:0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Printing
function printMyMap(){
   let myMapHTML= document.getElementById("myMap");
   let mywindow = window.open("", "PrintTheMap","width=600,height=800");

 let header = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet"  href="/your path/Site.css" media="print" /> <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/your path/leaflet.css" /> </head>
 //Adding the header to the window
 mywindow.document.write(header);
 //Adding the map into the body
 mywindow.document.write("<body>"+myMapHTML+"<body>");
 mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
 mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
 mywindow.print();
 mywindow.close();

}
```